# Get push notification on new question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I follow two specific tags: `[*worklight*]`, `[*mobilefirst*]` (everything under worklight-* and everything under mobilefile-*.

These tags are not too high volume; something like 10 questions a day.
It would be great, for me, if the app would get a notification whenever a *new* question is submitted. It could function as an option you can enable in your account either in the website or the app...